# Biblatex - how to use organization's acronym in in-text citation, and full name in the references?

Tags: biblatex

I am referencing a data booklet, produced by the International Baccalaureate Organization. I wish to use the abbreviated in-text citation of:

> (IBO, 2016)

However, I wish to have the full name in the references:

> International Baccalaureate Organization (2016). Physics data booklet. Cardiff: International Baccalaureate Organization (UK) Ltd.

How do I do this?

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex} % Referencing
\bibliography{test.bib}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}

@book{ib,
    author = {{International Baccalaureate Organization}},
    title = {Physics data booklet},
    publisher = {International Baccalaureate Organization (UK) Ltd},
    date = {2016-11},
    location = {Cardiff}
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum \parencite{ib}.

\printbibliography
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

Which outputs:

[image]

Comment: `\bibliography` takes the file name *without* extension. So it should be `\bibliography{test}` in your example. Better yet, use `\addbibresource` (*with* file extension).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is exactly what `shortauthor` was made for.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ib,
  author      = {{International Baccalaureate Organization}},
  shortauthor = {{IBU}},
  title       = {Physics data booklet},
  publisher   = {International Baccalaureate Organization (UK) Ltd},
  date        = {2016-11},
  location    = {Cardiff}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum \parencite{ib}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem ipsum (IBU, 2016).//References//International Baccalaureate Organization (Nov. 2016). Physics data booklet. Cardiff: International Baccalaureate Organization (UK) Ltd.]